# How were quarks made?

Tags: cosmology, universe, higgs, big-bang, quarks

I recently read about the early universe and found that first quarks were made $10^{-12}$ seconds after the inflation or the beginning.

But what was the cause of this minute delay, since inflation started when the universe was $10^{-34}$ seconds old (as per this image).

[image]

So basically I want to know why did it take that much time to form the first quarks? Also how much time should it take energy to form quarks at laboratories?

I know that nothing sure can be said about this but I want some ideas regarding this. Also, the time intervals are approx values given on the websites.

**Edit:** why didn't we have a **massive** quark (more massive than top quark or even anything else) if too much energy was present in a small space??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quarks were thought to be created from the potential energy of the decaying "inflaton" field *at the end* of the inflationary epoch. Any particles present prior to inflation would have become diluted to essentially zero number density by inflation. Indeed, this was one of the early motivations for the inflation theory - it successfully explained why we don't see exotic objects like magnetic monopoles, because their number density is extraordinarily low post-inflation.

At this point in time the weak force and electromagnetic force were unified and all the particles present (quarks, W, Z, gluons, photons, Higgs) were massless.

It was not until at around $10^{-12}$ s and [electroweak symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#:%7E:text=At%20a%20critical%20temperature%2C%20the,breaking%22%2C%20or%20EWSB), that particles attained their masses via the Higgs mechanism and became the particles we know in the standard model.

At $10^{-12}$ s, the universe had a temperature roughly equivalent to the [electroweak scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_scale) of 160 GeV. This energy scale sets roughly the maximum mass of particles that can be created at that time and indeed the top quark has a mass of around 170 GeV.

Comment: Jefferies What does it mean that the particles were massless ??

Comment: why didn't they gain more mass ?? Why were they restricted to their presently known mass ?

Comment: @Ankit particles get their mass via the Higgs mechanism. This took place along with electroweak symmetry breaking.  Massless particles exist now - they are called photons.

Comment: Jefferies does the Higgs field give masses to a limited amount ?? Or why didn't the Higgs mechanism resulted in an extremely massive quark ??

Comment: "Any particles present prior to inflation would have become diluted to essentially zero density by inflation.", can you please tell me what you mean by that? Point particles (elementary) do not have density. Inflation just would bring them father from each other, but they would still exist.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei assuming particle number is conserved then particle number density is reduced to close to zero by inflation.

Comment: By "density", he means "number of particles per unit volume of space", not the density of the particle itself, which is, as you say, a single point.

Comment: What kind of particles existed before inflation? @ProfRob

Comment: @VeronicaNoordzee "it successfully explained why we don't see exotic objects like magnetic monopoles," amongst other things. Not my speciality.

Comment: Quarks and Higgs-boson massless at the end of inflation. Really? @ProfRob

Comment: AFAIK in the Standard Model, at temperatures high enough that electroweak symmetry is unbroken, all elementary particles are massless @VeronicaNordzee

Comment: @ProfRob Thanks. That's exactly what I read today: http://sciexplorer.blogspot.com/2011/01/our-universe-part-6-electroweak-epoch.html

Answer (score 1):

Above a certain temperature, quarks get annihilated as quickly as they form. the universe had to cool off a bit to get below that threshold temperature, so the quarks would persist. Then they acquire their mass at about 10^-12 seconds.

Comment: By temperature did you mean that a huge amount of energy was present in a very compact space (since temperature is the measure of internal energy of the molecules and there were no molecules) ?? Also if a huge amount of energy was present then why didn't they form a massive quark ??

Comment: $10^{-12}$ s is when quarks attain their mass. It is not the epoch that they appear in the universe.

Comment: Thanks @RobJeffries, will edit. BTW when then do they then "appear"?

Comment: @Ankit Pretty sure you don't need molecules (as evidenced by Helium gas having a temperature). Anything that emits blackbody radiation can be said to have a real temperature (as opposed to effective temperature). Failing that, just use the amount of energy and/or entropy present as an approximate indicator