# Why quarks have limited mass?

Tags: cosmology, universe, quarks

I wanna ask why were the mass of first quarks not something like a very large number (because a lot of energy was present in that expanding universe) or much more than what we know from calculations ?

In my previous question ([How were quarks made?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/571818/how-were-quarks-made)) I came to know that quarks formation is explained by Higgs mechanism but does it also tell why do they have a certain fixed mass and why not an unimaginable mass or different from presently known values i.e why are there only six quarks ?

Comment: The same question can be asked about *any* fundamental particle with mass. Is there a reason why you are asking specifically about quarks instead of, say, electrons?

Comment: @G. Smith because quarks are the most fundamental particles or the first particles appeared in the universe ( till known)

Comment: Quarks are no more fundamental than any other fundamental particle. I have never heard of the idea that quarks appeared before, say, electrons, so I don’t believe it. Do you have a credible reference that supports your claim?

Comment: Do you understand the Yukawa coupling that gives quarks mass in  the Standard Model when the Higgs field gets a nonzero vacuum expectation value?

Comment: @G. Smith But quarks appeared first than protons or say atoms . So I termed them fundamental with respect to the atoms.

Comment: @G. Smith I am a high school student and don't know much about Higgs field and Yukawa coupling and I can't even understand them from Wikipedia as they use terms which I have never heard of.

Comment: @G. Smith can you explain why and how Yukawa coupling restricts the mass of quarks to presently known values ? Does it account for the reason why they don't have extreme masses like that of even stars ?

Comment: The Yukawa couplings that determine the masses are simply parameters of the Standard Model. I am not aware of any constraints on them that would restrict masses. But in the current Standard Model, Lorentz invariance requires them to be constants, so the resulting mass is *fixed*.

Answer (score 0):

If a particle has infinite mass, it takes with $E=mc^2$ an infinite amount of energy to produce it and it would produce an unlimited amount of energy if it decays. To my knowledge, we unfortunately do not have sources of an unlimited amount of energy, so it is impossible to create such particles. One could assume that it was possible to create such a particle under some crazy circumstances somewhere in the past, then it may decay today. However, there are no signs for such events yet.

You can always include particle with infinite mass in your theory. In our world with limited energies, they will never be created, and therefore your theory will the same predictions as the same theory without the infinite-mass-particle.

However, one requirement for a good theory is that it is as simple as possible. Therefore, particles with infinite mass are simply unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, but wouldn't the extra assumption that mass can *not* be arbitrarily high, aka infinite, be fodder for Occam's Razor?

Comment: @jonas I didn't mean infinite mass literally. I just wanna say mass other than that of known values since there was only energy and they could have formed extreme masses with that energy.

Comment: @Zaaikort my point is that one can assume infinite masses but one finds out that this has no influence on experiments because they cant be produced.

Comment: @Ankit quark masses are free parameters in the standard model that cant be fixed by symmetry arguments. We can only find them if we actually measure them(which is not simple since we cant observe them directly). So yes, the energyis high and heavier quarks were possible, but they just have the mass they have :)

Comment: @jonas is it possible that we could find them in future if their existence has no problem with the law of physics ?

Comment: @Ankit Quarks have known masses, they wont change. But it is possible(and a hot research topic) to search for theories that solve the problems of existing theories, and they may include new particles with very high masses that we didnt find so far since they are too heavy or too weakly interacting(like sterile neutrinos). I dont think that there is a useful way of including particles with infinite mass in a theory.